# Morris js Display values in percentage format

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I am drawing some charts for a school project pulling data from a mysql database.
Here is what I've done so far:

**DONUT CHARTS**

JS CODE:

```
Morris.Donut({
    element: 'donut-quanti',
    data: [
    {label: "USE FACEBOOK", value: <?php echo $fb_yes;?> },
    {label: "DON'T USE FACEBOOK", value: <?php echo $fb_no;?>}
    ]
    });
```

**BAR CHARTS**

JS CODE:

```
Morris.Bar({
        element: 'bars-status',
        data: [
        {x:'RARELY',a:<?php echo $fb_rar;?>},
        {x:'EV WEEK.',a:<?php echo $fb_ew;?>},
        {x:'EV DAY',a:<?php echo $fb_ed;?>},
        {x:'MULT. TIMES PER DAY',a:<?php echo $fb_mtd;?>}                   
        ],
        xkey:'x',
        ykeys:'a',
        labels:['TOTAL']
        });
```

Is there a way to display the numeric values (rapresented by the php variables $fb_*)  **IN PERCENTAGE FORMAT from javascript code**  (not echoing variable/total * 100 in php ) ?

Comment: are you trying to format the axis, or the number that shows up when the mouse hovers over a point?

Comment: the number that shows up when the mouse hovers

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For the donut you need to use the `formatter` parameter

```
formatter: function (value, data) { return (value/total *100) + '%'; }
```

See: http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/donuts.html

---

For the bar you need to use hover callback

```
hoverCallback: function (index, options, content) {
  var row = options.data[index];
  //assumes you have already calculated the total of your own dataset
  return (value/total *100)+'%';
}
```

See: http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/bars.html

Comment: I read the documentation but I can't understand that part...what is y referring to in the donut chart example?

Comment: its just a function argument referring to the "value" part of a donut {"label":"value"} pair, it could be anything but the function docs use y. I've edited that one to maybe make it clearer

Comment: Morris.Donut({
     element: 'donut-quanti',
     data: [
    {label: "USANO FACEBOOK", value: <?php echo $fb_si;?> },
    {label: "NON USANO FACEBOOK", value: <?php echo $fb_no;?>}
    ]
    formatter:function(value,data){return 'value*<?php echo $v_android;?>/100'+'%';}
   });

Comment: There is an error in your answer for the donut, it should be 

    formatter: function (value, data) { return value/100 + '%'; }

(remove the strings around value / 100)

Comment: @DiamondFox thanks, you are correct there. Also, I'm looking at this, shouldn't it be something like `(value/total * 100)+'%'`?

Comment: Yes you also need the brackets. I had put them in on mine without even thinking! Good spot.

Comment: For both examples you need to calculate the 'total' somewhere first.

Answer (score 1):

To add the percentage symbol, please use this property.
I did not find this in the docs but it works perfectly.
 postUnits: ["%"]

Answer (score 0):

```
donutChartOptions = {
    resize: true,
    colors: ["#8e54e9", "#4776e6"],
    formatter: function (value) { return (value) + '%'; }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.